# Godaddy - folder with password protection

Tags: web-hosting, security, godaddy, authentication

Godaddy windows shared hosting on IIS6, but will probably migrate to IIS7 soon.

Is there easy way to setup folder with password protection, so when I try to access secure folder, login dialog pops up?

Comment: is this question for this stackexchange or should it be moved to "Web Applications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question? http://help.godaddy.com/article/3977

It requires you to enter your Godaddy hosting username and password to access the directory as a result, so I'm not sure if that's what you want (you did not mention giving access to other users - if it's only for you then this probably works fine, but obviously not if anyone else needs to access it.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have done something similar was to add a sub domain, and then create an ftp account to that domain. So when you go to example.com/foldername it asks for your credentials.  Probably not what you were looking for....